# Hp laserjet 1018 printer keeps asking me to install it everytime I plug it in

Tags: printing, hp, laserjet

I just upgraded to Ubuntu 11.04 Beta 2 from Ubuntu 10.10 on my netbook (a Dell Mini 1012). The problem is I have a HP Laserjet 1018 printer which I had it installed in Ubuntu 10.10 without any problems.

But after I've upgraded to 11.04, every time I plug it in it asks for downloading the proprietary plugin and installs it then when I remove the cable and plug it in again it downloads the plugin again.

I never had this problem in 10.10. Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

the answer in [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=10877575&postcount=9) posting solved this problem for me.

In short:

```
sudo getweb 1018
sudo hplj1018
```

Answer (score 1):

It is bug in hplip of ubuntu 14.04: https://bugs.launchpad.net/hplip/+bug/1315408

The workaround is to downgrade hplip to the version from ubuntu 13.10:

1. Remove hplip of 14.04 (for some reason apt-get won't do that automatically)

   ```
   apt-get remove hplip
   ```
2. Add repo strings for 13.10

   ```
   cat > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/saucy.list <<EOF
   deb http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy main restricted
   deb http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy universe
   deb http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy multiverse
   EOF
   ```
3. Update apt's db

   ```
   apt-get update
   ```
4. install hplip of 13.10

   ```
   apt-get install hplip=3.13.9-1 libhpmud0=3.13.9-1 libsane-hpaio=3.13.9-1 \
       hplip-data=3.13.9-1 printer-driver-hpcups=3.13.9-1
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of installing the proprietary plugin, try [HPLIP](http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/index.html). 
(Since 11.04 is beta, this may be a bug as well)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem

Deleted the printer installation, turned it off and unplugged the USB connector

Opened the Synaptic Package Manager and removed HPLIP, HPLIP DATA, and HPLIP CUPS

Shut the computer down, then restarted and installed the removed packages.  Connected the USB cable and turned the printer on.  The system installed the printer automatically without any plugin downloads and printed normally.  Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I also had a problem with my HP 1018 printer upon upgrading to Ubuntu 11.04 Natty Narwhal. I tried gymador's suggestion but it didn't work. This is what worked for me

1. Make sure you have "hplip" installed in Synaptic
2. Go to the terminal and type `sudo hp-setup -i` and follow the prompts
   to install the driver/plugin

It should work now

EDIT: Actually, the process I outlined above only worked for one print of a document and failed again afterwards. I then tried this to make it work:
1. go to Synaptic and install "hplip-gui"
2. go to the dash and type in "hplip" and launch "hplip toolbox"
3. Click on the HP laserjet 1018 on the left
4. make sure you're on the actions tab
5. click download firmware
6. try printing something

It worked again for me, but I don't know if it'll keep working afterwards though.